# Integrating Google Apis with Rails (Missing token endpoint URI Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-api

I want to use google apis in my app.

I successful get my access token but I am getting error :-

**"Missing token endpoint URI."**

My code is

```
def calender
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])
    drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
    drive.authorization = client
    files = drive.list_files
end
```

when I printed my client variable, it showed my these details

```
#<Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService:0x0000010cc287f8 
@root_url="https://www.googleapis.com/",
 @base_path="drive/v3/", 
 @upload_path="upload/drive/v3/", 
 @batch_path="batch", 


 @client_options=#<struct Google::Apis::ClientOptions application_name="unknown", application_version="0.0.0", proxy_url=nil, use_net_http=false>, 

 @request_options=#<struct Google::Apis::RequestOptions 
 authorization=#<Signet::OAuth2::Client:0x0000010cc288c0 
 @authorization_uri=nil, 
 @token_credential_uri=nil, 
 @client_id=nil, 
 @client_secret=nil, 
 @code=nil, 
 @expires_at=nil, 
 @expires_in=nil,
  @issued_at=nil, 
  @issuer=nil, 
  @password=nil,
   @principal=nil, 
   @redirect_uri=nil, 
   @scope=nil, 
   @state=nil, 
   @username=nil, 
   @expiry=60, 
   @extension_parameters={}, 
   @additional_parameters={},
    @access_token="ya29.CjAbA8B7CFyhBLhFuEtP6kmCmuvJESwClkchiPpydjAqBOvDuvDERVCSVrYSSWLZvZc">, retries=0, 
    header=nil, 
    timeout_sec=nil, 
    open_timeout_sec=20>
```

I have spent two days to resolve this and explored whole internet but my issue is not resolved. My issue is related to already reported issue :-
[Missing token endpoint URI while using a valid access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089763/missing-token-endpoint-uri-while-using-a-valid-access-token)
But solution provided in it is also not working for me. There is no attribute of "authentication" that I can use to assign my token.

I would greatly appreciate if someone help me with this.

Comment: Did you work this out?

Comment: No. I had found an alternative work around to access my google sheet through google_drive gem. But this issue of actually getting whole access of google drive via authentication is still not found out by me. Right now I am not on it but I would definitely work more on it to find out a solution of this.