# Rails google analytics apis error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

What does this error signify?

`Missing token endpoint URI.` highlighted at @account_summaries

```
def analytics
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token]['access_token'])

        service = Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3::AnalyticsService.new

        service.authorization = client

        @account_summaries = service.list_account_summaries
end
```

I tried searching everywhere, but can't understand in context of Google Analytics API what does this even mean?

Technically, the code should just work, but for some reason its not playing nice. Where exactly is it going wrong?

Full code

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

    def redirect
      client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
        client_id: 'APP ID',
        client_secret: 'APP SECRET',
        authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        scope: Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3::AUTH_ANALYTICS_READONLY,
        redirect_uri: url_for(:action => :oauth2callback)
        additional_parameters: { access_type: :offline, approval_prompt: :force }
      })

      redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
    end

    def oauth2callback
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
        client_id: 'APP ID',
        client_secret: 'APP SECRET',
        token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        redirect_uri: url_for(:action => :oauth2callback),
        code: params[:code]
      })

      response = client.fetch_access_token!

      session[:access_token] = response['access_token']

      redirect_to url_for(:action => :analytics)

    end

    def analytics
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token]['access_token'])

        service = Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3::AnalyticsService.new

        service.authorization = client

        @account_summaries = service.list_account_summaries
    end

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing token endpoint URI while using a valid access\_token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089763/missing-token-endpoint-uri-while-using-a-valid-access-token)

Comment: It would be really helpful if there is some guidance on the problem.

Comment: In fact I had tried that approach, it didn't workout. Was still getting the same error.

Comment: @arjun 
have you get the client and secret? usually to complete the validation process you need to ask to the user with your redirect uri, secret and project id. Only then , this json comes back with an autorization code and pushing this code to the google's server aggain, you can get the token.

Try to print the token out, to see if you're current getting this. only when you get the token (and the refresh token) you can ask for the information on the server. 
Check the flow here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
and remmeber fill al the field correctly